# KnockoutJS Mapping from Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I"m been tasked with doing a POC of KnockoutJS and running into an issue that I just can't figure out.

I want to retrieve the data from a service using Ajax and then populate the form with ko.mapping.fromJS().  My form will not populate when I call the mapping from within the success function of the ajax call.  If I move it outside the success then it works fine.

UPDATE: I do know that the load function does get called in my jsfiddle (put an alert inside there and it does fire) but the form does not populate..

http://jsfiddle.net/Ud9ex/6/

```
var planDesignData = {
        RecordID: '1124',
        Name: "Main"            
    };


var PlanDesignModel = function () {
var self = this;            

//*** As soon as I move this line inside the sucess the input doesn't get populated 
self.planDesign = ko.mapping.fromJS(planDesignData);

self.load = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",                    
        success: function (data) {                       
            var loadedPD = {};

            //I want to run the mapping here

        }
    });
}
}


$(document).ready(function () {
            var viewModel = new PlanDesignModel();
            viewModel.load();
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);    

        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you get if you do console.log(data) in the success function?

Comment: Well, in my jsfiddle I get nothing.  If I do it on my local I can see the data.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ud9ex/10/)

All you need to do is send data to `/echo/json`.

I did do a `defer` in this example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = new PlanDesignModel();
    $.when(viewModel.load).always(function(){
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
});
```

But everything works just fine:

```
success: function (data) {
            var loadedPD = {};
            console.log(data);
            self.planDesign = ko.mapping.fromJS(planDesignData);
            //I want to run the mapping here

        }
```

Note, I did put 1 second delay:

```
data: {
            json: JSON.stringify({
                RecordID: '1124',
                Name: "Main"
            }),
            delay: 1
        },
```

Comment: Does this work on GET? I have no data initially. I'm still having trouble with this.

Comment: I might not be the best idea to use hard-coded delays. Callbacking will be the best solution here.